# Is there any way to shorten this Python generator expression?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, generator, list-comprehension

I need to build a generator and I was looking for a way to shorten this for loop into a single line. I tried enumerate but that did not work.

```
counter=0
for element in string:
    if function(element):
        counter+=1
        yield counter
    else:
        yield counter
```

Comment: Are you missing a `counter=0`, or is this supposed to be a closure around whatever `counter` is in the outer code?

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: No, I excluded it initially, but I just included it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
counter=0
for element in string:
    counter+=bool(function(element))
    yield counter
```

(Yes, adding Booleans to ints works exactly as if `True` was `1` and `False` was `0`).

The `bool()` call is only necessary if `function()` can have return values other than `True`, `False`, `1`, and `0`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Python 3, you can do:

```
from itertools import accumulate

yield from accumulate(1 if function(x) else 0 for x in string)
```

Although I'd use [Simeon Visser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16310487/464744). While this one may be short, it isn't immediately clear what the code does.

Comment: @jamylak: You aren't left with a `counter` variable at the end.

Comment: This won't work unless `function` explicitly returns 0 and 1. If it returns, say, `None` or a string, you'll get `TypeError`s all over. Even if it returns `True` and `False`, the very first value will be `False` instead of `0`.

Comment: I'm not sure what "I'm assuming `accumulate` returns a boolean" means. It returns an iterator. And it's an iterator over whatever addable type you give it (or, rather, over the result of adding whatever type you give it—not quite the same thing, because, e.g., `False+True == 1`, or, in older Python, `(1<<31) + (1<<31) = (1L<<32)`).

Comment: @abarnert: Sorry, `accumulate` should've been `function`

Comment: @Blender: Then it's still wrong, because, as I explained before, the first value you yield will be `False`, not `0`.

Comment: @Blender: OK, now you just have to change the `c` to `x` so it can be 100% identical to my answer. :)

Comment: @abarnert: Done. Although I have the `yield from` and `accumulate` as a global, so it's only about 80% identical.

Comment: Which means your answer is a good argument for anyone on 3.1 to upgrade to 3.3 (to get `yield from`, which rocks), while mine is only an argument to upgrade to 3.2 (to get `accumulate` without copy-pasting the recipe, which is pretty trivial). And life would be better if nobody were using 3.0-3.2 anymore. :)

Answer (score 4):

First, you can transform the string into an iterator over the `function` return values:

```
truths = (function(x) for x in string)
```

Then you can map those to 0s and 1s:

```
onesandzeroes = (1 if function(x) else 0 for x in string)
```

And then [accumulate](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) them:

```
running = itertools.accumulate(1 if function(x) else 0 for x in string)
```

As the docs note, `accumulate` was added in Python 3.2. If you're using 2.x, you can copy and paste the "Equivalent to" recipe from the docs. (If you're using 3.0-3.1, you can do the same, but really, in that case, just upgrade.)

Answer (score 3):

You could shorten it to:

```
counter=0
for element in string:
    if function(element):
        counter+=1
    yield counter
```

Comment: I need to keep a running count, so I need to yield with the else statement as well.

Comment: @garlfd: this still yields with every element in the string, it only updates it for some elements.